# Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Password hashing (prompt without echo) uses the java.io.Console to read passwords safely

Tags: java, hash, shiro

When I tried to run the shiro-tools-hasher-1.2.0-cli.jar for hashing password facing error.

```
C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\shiro\tools\shiro-tools-hasher\1.2.0>java -jar shiro-tools-hasher-1.2.0-cli.jar -p -d
```

Error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Password hashing (prompt without
>   echo) uses the java.io.Console to read passwords safely.  This is only
>   available on Java 1.6 platforms and later.
>           at org.apache.shiro.tools.hasher.Hasher.readPassword(Hasher.java:412)
>           at org.apache.shiro.tools.hasher.Hasher.main(Hasher.java:164) Password hashing (prompt without echo) uses the java.io.Console to
>   read passwords safely.  This is only available on Java 1.6 platforms
>   and later.

Comment: I found code for Hash in the following link but unable to resolve the issue,

Comment: _"This is only available on Java 1.6 platforms and later. "_ what Java version are you running?

Comment: http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/shiro-tools/shiro-tools-hasher/cobertura/org.apache.shiro.tools.hasher.Hasher.html

Comment: I am using java 1.8_161 version, even though I am facing same error

Comment: Are you sure? You are running whatever `java` on the path.

Comment: C:\Users\admin>java -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: I am referring following link, https://shiro.apache.org/command-line-hasher.html#command-line-hasher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, this was fixed in v`1.2.6`, but you should be using at least v`1.3.2`.

Comment: Thank you after changing shiro version to 1.3.2 I am able to hash the password

Answer (score -1):

Looks like shiro's [`JavaEnvironment`](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.3.2/xref/org/apache/shiro/util/JavaEnvironment.html) needs to be updated to support Java 8. It currently considers Java 8 the same as Java 1.3.

Comment: Use version 1.3.2 or higher